# CPanel Database Import Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to run this MySQL database code, but this error is holding me back:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'U' at line 1"

Code:

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object: Database [MathDB] Script Date: 2/13/2017 7:49:31 PM ******/
CREATE DATABASE [MathDB]
CONTAINMENT = NONE
ON PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'MathDB', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MathDB.mdf' , SIZE = 3072KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
LOG ON 
( NAME = N'MathDB_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MathDB_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 204[...]
```

Thanks.

Comment: The tags and code is Microsoft SQL Server (T-SQL) code, but the error message clearly is **MySQL** - you need to explain what's going on here!!

Comment: You can not just copy and paste from one database engine to another one. Please check the MySQL syntax and transform your command.

Comment: I'm really lost out here, what should I do?